Scipy butterworth filter sos (second order sections) output - what it is and what is the benefit?
scipy butterworth filter has sos output option. Please help understand what it is and what the benefit in layman's term.

output{‘ba’, ‘zpk’, ‘sos’}, optional
Type of output: numerator/denominator (‘ba’), pole-zero (‘zpk’), or second-order sections (‘sos’). Default is ‘ba’ for backwards compatibility, but ‘sos’ should be used for general-purpose filtering.

Googled second order sections. Most articles lists math formulas and electric circuits and unable to find simple explanation.
According to ChatGPT, it looks a way to build N order filter as a cascade of multiple 2nd order filters, but not sure this ChatGPT answer is correct or relevant to scipy output option.

Higher-order filters can be constructed by cascading multiple second-order sections. This cascade structure simplifies the design and implementation process, as well as the optimization of filter performance.
Imagine you're building a really sophisticated filter for sound or data signals. Instead of making it all in one big complicated piece, you split it into smaller parts that are easier to handle. Each of these smaller parts is called a "second-order section."
In summary, "second-order sections" refer to the subdivision of a higher-order filter into smaller, more manageable second-order building blocks. This approach enhances flexibility, stability, efficiency, and ease of implementation in both analog and digital filter designs.

How to implement band-pass Butterworth filter with Scipy.signal.butter indicated stability but not sure it is specific to scipy implementation and not sos in general.

SciPy bandpass filters designed with b, a are unstable and may result in erroneous filters at higher filter orders. Instead, use sos (second-order sections) output of filter design.


SOS is definitely the way to go. However, the reasons behind this are deeply mathematical. What is  you mathematical background? Are you familiar with Z-transform,  linear difference equations, poles & zeros of filters, finding the roots of a polynomial ?  "Layman's terms" really depend on the background of the lay person.  And yes: ChatGPT is correct:

@Hilmar, thanks for the follow up. I am not at that level (yet), so for now, having a confirmation of chatgpt is correct is a starting point. Thanks agian.

If you consider a first-order filter (with a single pole or zero), the pole or zero must be on the real axis to have a filter with real coefficients.
For a second-order filter (with two poles or zeros), the poles or zeros must be paired with their conjugates to ensure coefficients are real. Each of these pair form a second order section. So, basically, there is no other way to get an arbitrary filter with real coefficients.
The important question is how to pair zero pairs with pole pairs (as numerator and denumerator of second order section transfer function) and the order which SOS are cascaded. Usually nearest zero and pole paired together and SOS with highest Q factor comes first, which reduces computational noise and improves stability.

Normally you implementing a direct-form filter from the numerator and denominator polynomials.
It would seem like the best thing to do is to just implement a filter of the same order as your polynomial. However, there are two problems with this.
First, as your filter order goes up, the sensitivity of the filter's pole positions to the values of the coefficients goes up roughly as the power of the filter order.  For $a \simeq 1$, $z - a \pm \epsilon$ has a root at $z = a \pm \epsilon$, $(z - a)^2 \pm \epsilon$ has roots about $\sqrt \epsilon$ away from $a$, and $(z - a)^n \pm \epsilon$ has roots about $\sqrt[n]{\epsilon}$ away from $a$.
This means that as the filter order goes up, the precision you need in your coefficients (particularly the trailing one) goes up rapidly.  This effect is significantly more pronounced when your filter is relatively narrow with respect to the sampling rate, because your pole position $a$ ends up being closer to the unit circle, and the filter behavior is most heavily affected by where the poles are with respect to the unit circle.
For similar reasons, as the filter order goes up the sensitivity of the filter to errors to noise injected at any stage goes up as well, to roughly the same amount.  So not only does the required coefficient precision go up, but so does the datapath precision.
It is very easy to avoid both of these problems by building your filter as a cascade of second-order sections (with one first-order section if it's of odd order).  This minimizes both of the effects above.
It's pretty much standard practice in the DSP world -- so, Matlab supports this by giving you the second order sections already precomputed.
